# .htaccess RewriteRule to get pretty links

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have URLs like:

```
1) http://www.example.com/?page=2
2) http://www.example.com/my-photos-folder?page=3
```

Here page number will increase sequentially (page=1, page=2, page=3 .....).

"my-photos-folder" Can be anything like "my-images-folder"  or "Nice-photos"  etc..

What i would like to get:

```
1) http://www.example.com/page/2
2) http://www.example.com/my-photos-folder/page/3
```

My .htaccess has the following rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^page\/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?kohana_uri=$1 [QSA,PT,L]
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?kohana_uri=$1 [QSA,PT,L]
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*) $1 [QSA,R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Can any expert suggest me what rules i need to add so that my desired outcome will be achived. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add theese lines after the `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteRule ^page\/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/page\/(.*)$ $1?page=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Hi Develroot thanks for suggestion but... "kim-sharma-hot-photos" Can be anything like "Nargis-Fakhri-Wallpepers"  or "Poonam-Pandey-Hot-Photos" how to resolve this...Thank you in advance.

Comment: Second Rule still don't work may be something needs to be added. Thanks for your help first rule work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

@develroot

```
RewriteRule ^page\/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]  //This is working fine for homepage
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/page\/(.*)$ $1?page=$2 [L]   //this rule still not working on directory level.
```

The second one still have issue. Please consider the rules which are already there.[I have updated the question - added your first rule which work fine.]

Comment: what do you mean by `directory level`. is there a folder called `my-photos-folder`?

Comment: @Develroot   my-photos-folder, my-images-folder and "Nice-photos" are folders which have photos.

Comment: and what exactly are you trying to achive? is there a index.php in each of those folders?

Comment: 1) this is the url - http://hotcineactress.com/Sonakshi-Sinha-Hot-Wallpapers?page=2 what i want is in this form -  http://hotcineactress.com/Sonakshi-Sinha-Hot-Wallpapers/page/2

2) no index.php is not there in those folders. before all above rewrite it will display something like this. --

http://hotcineactress.com/index.php/Sonakshi-Sinha-Hot-Wallpapers?page=2

Comment: if i right something like this...    RewriteRule ^(.*)\/page\/(.*)$ index.php/$1?page=$2 [NC,L]   it will work but this is redirecting back to old url ..   e.g  http://127.0.0.1/ileana/page/3  will display the photos.. but in address bar it is going back to http://127.0.0.1/ileana?page=3

Comment: that's because of the next line `
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?kohana_uri=$1 [QSA,PT,L]` and that's how kohana works and i don't know anything you can do about it.

Comment: No luck...is there anything i can do about it...and get it fixed